# Why can't I pass data from my ViewController to my custom UIView using a delegate? (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, delegates, protocols

I have a ViewController (`oneUserDetailsViewController`) which I want to use to control a UIView (`weeklyLog`). To make the UIView work, I need to pass data in two NSArray's (`morningRecord` and `nighttimeRecord`) from the ViewController to the UIView.

I have set up a Protocol (`WeeklyLogDataSource`) in the UIView with two functions (`morningLogForWeeklyLogView` and `nighttimeLogForWeeklyLogView`) designed to return the two NSArray's from the delegate (in this case the ViewController) to the UIView.

In the UIView, I have declared the protocol (`dataSource`) and then created the code in the UIView to access the returned NSArrays.

In the ViewController, I have added the delegate to the class declaration, set the delegate to self and then implemented the two functions to return the two NSArray's.

As far as I know, I have set this up correctly. However, when I run the application, the data is not passed from the View Controller to the UIView and instead the UIView displays the default data `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`. Using a Print command, I can see that the declared Protocol (`dataSource`) in the UIView is showing as nil, which I assume is the root of my problem. But I do not know how to resolve it.

Can you help?

Here is the code from the UIView:

```
import UIKit

// Delegate
protocol WeeklyLogDataSource: class {

  func morningLogForWeeklyLogView(sender: weeklyLog) -> NSArray?
  func nighttimeLogForWeeklyLogView(sender: weeklyLog) -> NSArray?

}


class weeklyLog: UIView
{

  // MARK: Properties

  weak var dataSource: WeeklyLogDataSource?

  var topRowImages = [UIImageView]()
  var secondRowImages = [UIImageView]()
  var bottomRowLabels = [UITextView]()
  let labelsForTextViews = ["", "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"]
  let spacing = 5
  let columns = 8
  var morningRecord:NSArray! {
    didSet {
      setNeedsLayout()
      setNeedsDisplay()
    }
  }
  var nighttimeRecord:NSArray! {
    didSet {
      setNeedsLayout()
      setNeedsDisplay()
    }
  }



  func setup() {
    print("setup in weeklyLog called")

    if let morningLog:NSArray = dataSource?.morningLogForWeeklyLogView(self) {
      morningRecord = morningLog
    } else {
      morningRecord = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    }

    if let nighttimeLog:NSArray = dataSource?.nighttimeLogForWeeklyLogView(self) {
      nighttimeRecord = nighttimeLog
    } else {
      nighttimeRecord = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    }

    print("morningRecord: \(morningRecord)")
    print("nighttimeRecord: \(nighttimeRecord)")

  }


  // MARK: Initialisation

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    setup()
    setNeedsLayout()

    print("dataSource: \(dataSource)")

  }

  override func layoutSubviews() {

    // Set the width and height of each image in proportion to the frame's size.
    let imageViewHeight = Int(Double(frame.size.height) * (Double(frame.size.height)/Double(frame.size.width)))
    let imageViewWidth = Int(Double(frame.size.width)/Double(columns)) - spacing
    var imageViewFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: imageViewWidth, height: imageViewHeight)

    // Offset each image's origin by the width of the image.
    // top row
    for (index, imageView) in topRowImages.enumerate() {

      imageViewFrame.origin.x = CGFloat(index * (imageViewWidth + spacing))    // spacing is set in the Properties section near the top
      imageView.frame = imageViewFrame

    }

    // second row
    for (index, imageView) in secondRowImages.enumerate() {

      imageViewFrame.origin.x = CGFloat(index * (imageViewWidth + spacing))    // spacing is set in the Properties section near the top
      imageViewFrame.origin.y = CGFloat(imageViewHeight)
      imageView.frame = imageViewFrame

    }

    // bottom row
    for (index, textView) in bottomRowLabels.enumerate() {

      imageViewFrame.origin.x = CGFloat(index * (imageViewWidth + spacing))    // spacing is set in the Properties section near the top
      imageViewFrame.origin.y = CGFloat(imageViewHeight*2)
      textView.frame = imageViewFrame

    }


    // set images for top row
    for var i = 0; i < columns; i++ {

      let imageView = UIImageView()

      if i == 0 {
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "sun")
      } else {
        if (morningRecord[i-1] as! NSNumber) == 0 {
          imageView.image = UIImage(named: "star_grey")
        } else {
          imageView.image = UIImage(named: "star_gold")
        }
      }

      topRowImages += [imageView]
      addSubview(imageView)

    }

    // set images for second row
    for var i = 0; i < columns; i++ {

      let imageView = UIImageView()

      if i == 0 {
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "moon")
      } else {
        if (nighttimeRecord[i-1] as! NSNumber) == 0 {
          imageView.image = UIImage(named: "star_grey")
        } else {
          imageView.image = UIImage(named: "star_gold")
        }
      }

      secondRowImages += [imageView]
      addSubview(imageView)

    }

    // set labels for bottom row
    for var i = 0; i < columns; i++ {

      let logLabel = UITextView()

      logLabel.text = labelsForTextViews[i]
      logLabel.textAlignment = .Center
      logLabel.textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = 1;
      logLabel.editable = false
      logLabel.selectable = false

      bottomRowLabels += [logLabel]
      addSubview(logLabel)

    }

  }

  override func intrinsicContentSize() -> CGSize {

    let superViewHeight = Int(frame.size.height)
    let superViewWidth = Int(frame.size.width)

    return CGSize(width: superViewWidth, height: superViewHeight)

  }

}
```

Here is the code from the ViewController:

```
import UIKit

class oneUserDetailsViewController: UIViewController, WeeklyLogDataSource
    {

  @IBOutlet var logView: weeklyLog! {  // this is an outlet to the UIView in my Storyboard
    didSet {
      logView.dataSource = self
    }
  }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

  func morningLogForWeeklyLogView(sender: weeklyLog) -> NSArray? {

    let morningLog:NSArray = [0,1,0,1,0,1,0]
    return morningLog
  }

  func nighttimeLogForWeeklyLogView(sender: weeklyLog) -> NSArray? {

    let nightLog:NSArray = [0,1,0,1,0,1,0]
    return nightLog
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Anton. Your answer gave the seed of the solution and I have fixed it now.

I wasn't able to create a function in the *UIView* that calls the protocol methods as such (as I discovered, the protocol methods are not accessible within the *UIView* itself), but what I did do was call the *UIView*'s *setup()* function from the *ViewController*. In the end, rather than putting it in *ViewDidAppear* I put it within *didSet {..}* for the outlet to the instance of the *UIView*.

At first, calling *setup()* there was creating a duplicate version of the graphics in the *UIView*. The first one was being drawn using the default array *[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]*, the second one was being drawn using the arrays passed from the *ViewController*, but it was off the screen (not what I wanted).

To stop that I had to delete the code calling *setup()* that was in the initialisation function within the *UIView*. Calling *setup()* at that point was too early - it was causing *UIView* to draw the graphics using the default array. But when it was called from the *ViewController*, the *UIView* then called the protocol methods that are in the delegate *ViewController*, thus passing the correct arrays from the *ViewController* to the *UIView* - and, hey presto, it was fixed.

In case it's useful to anyone, here's my code now:

First, the UIView:

```
import UIKit

// Delegate
protocol WeeklyLogDataSource: class {

  func morningLogForWeeklyLogView(sender: weeklyLog) -> NSArray?
  func nighttimeLogForWeeklyLogView(sender: weeklyLog) -> NSArray?

}


class weeklyLog: UIView
{

  // MARK: Properties

  weak var dataSource: WeeklyLogDataSource?

  var topRowImages = [UIImageView]()
  var secondRowImages = [UIImageView]()
  var bottomRowLabels = [UITextView]()
  let labelsForTextViews = ["", "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"]
  let spacing = 5
  let columns = 8
  var morningRecord:NSArray! {
    didSet {
      setNeedsLayout()
      setNeedsDisplay()
    }
  }
  var nighttimeRecord:NSArray! {
    didSet {
      setNeedsLayout()
      setNeedsDisplay()
    }
  }



  func setup() {
    print("setup in weeklyLog called")

    if let morningLog:NSArray = dataSource?.morningLogForWeeklyLogView(self) {
      morningRecord = morningLog
    } else {
      morningRecord = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    }

    if let nighttimeLog:NSArray = dataSource?.nighttimeLogForWeeklyLogView(self) {
      nighttimeRecord = nighttimeLog
    } else {
      nighttimeRecord = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    }

    print("morningRecord: \(morningRecord)")
    print("nighttimeRecord: \(nighttimeRecord)")

  }


  // MARK: Initialisation

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    // I removed setup() from here

    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    print("dataSource: \(dataSource)")

  }

  override func layoutSubviews() {

    // Set the width and height of each image in proportion to the frame's size.
    let imageViewHeight = Int(Double(frame.size.height) * (Double(frame.size.height)/Double(frame.size.width)))
    let imageViewWidth = Int(Double(frame.size.width)/Double(columns)) - spacing
    var imageViewFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: imageViewWidth, height: imageViewHeight)

    // Offset each image's origin by the width of the image.
    // top row
    for (index, imageView) in topRowImages.enumerate() {

      imageViewFrame.origin.x = CGFloat(index * (imageViewWidth + spacing))    // spacing is set in the Properties section near the top
      imageView.frame = imageViewFrame

    }

    // second row
    for (index, imageView) in secondRowImages.enumerate() {

      imageViewFrame.origin.x = CGFloat(index * (imageViewWidth + spacing))    // spacing is set in the Properties section near the top
      imageViewFrame.origin.y = CGFloat(imageViewHeight)
      imageView.frame = imageViewFrame

    }

    // bottom row
    for (index, textView) in bottomRowLabels.enumerate() {

      imageViewFrame.origin.x = CGFloat(index * (imageViewWidth + spacing))    // spacing is set in the Properties section near the top
      imageViewFrame.origin.y = CGFloat(imageViewHeight*2)
      textView.frame = imageViewFrame

    }


    // set images for top row
    for var i = 0; i < columns; i++ {

      let imageView = UIImageView()

      if i == 0 {
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "sun")
      } else {
        if (morningRecord[i-1] as! NSNumber) == 0 {
          imageView.image = UIImage(named: "star_grey")
        } else {
          imageView.image = UIImage(named: "star_gold")
        }
      }

      topRowImages += [imageView]
      addSubview(imageView)

    }

    // set images for second row
    for var i = 0; i < columns; i++ {

      let imageView = UIImageView()

      if i == 0 {
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "moon")
      } else {
        if (nighttimeRecord[i-1] as! NSNumber) == 0 {
          imageView.image = UIImage(named: "star_grey")
        } else {
          imageView.image = UIImage(named: "star_gold")
        }
      }

      secondRowImages += [imageView]
      addSubview(imageView)

    }

    // set labels for bottom row
    for var i = 0; i < columns; i++ {

      let logLabel = UITextView()

      logLabel.text = labelsForTextViews[i]
      logLabel.textAlignment = .Center
      logLabel.textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = 1;
      logLabel.editable = false
      logLabel.selectable = false

      bottomRowLabels += [logLabel]
      addSubview(logLabel)

    }

  }

  override func intrinsicContentSize() -> CGSize {

    let superViewHeight = Int(frame.size.height)
    let superViewWidth = Int(frame.size.width)

    return CGSize(width: superViewWidth, height: superViewHeight)

  }

}
```

Second, the ViewController:

```
import UIKit

class oneUserDetailsViewController: UIViewController, WeeklyLogDataSource
    {

  @IBOutlet var logView: weeklyLog! {  // this is an outlet to the UIView in my Storyboard
    didSet {
      logView.dataSource = self
      logView.setup()  // this line is the magic! 
    }
  }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

  func morningLogForWeeklyLogView(sender: weeklyLog) -> NSArray? {

    let morningLog:NSArray = [0,1,0,1,0,1,0]
    return morningLog
  }

  func nighttimeLogForWeeklyLogView(sender: weeklyLog) -> NSArray? {

    let nightLog:NSArray = [0,1,0,1,0,1,0]
    return nightLog
  }

}
```